# Rails 3, confused about 'before_create :some_method' ... WHEN does some_method do its thing?

Tags: ruby, callback

we have model helper (used by several different models) called set_guids that sets self.theguid to a random string. Been using it for a long time, we know it works.

in a new model 'Dish' we created, we have

```
before_create :set_guids    (NOTE: no other before/after/validation, just this)

def do_meat_dish
  ( this is invoked by @somemeat.do_meat_dish in the Dish contoller )
  ( it manipulated the @somemeat object using self.this and self.that, works fine)

  ( THEN sometimes it creates a new object of SAME MODEL type )
  ( which is handled differently) 
    @veggie = Dish.new
    @veggie.do_veggie_dish
end

def do_veggie_dish
  recipe_str = "add the XXXX to water"
  recipe_str.gsub!("XXXX", self.theguid)  *** the PROBLEM: self.theguid is nil 
end
```

as soon as we execute `veggie = Dish.new` shouldn't `veggie.theguid` be initialized?

Note we have not **saved** the new object yet... but the before_create should still have done its thing, right?

it is something to do with create a new instance of a model inside a method for the same model?

is it something with using @ for the variables?

Additional note: if we comment out the line trying to access self.theguid everything else works fine ... it's ONLY the value (supposedly) set by the before_create set_guids that is nil instead of being a guid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before_create` is called only before the object is saved to the database the first time. That's why you get `nil`.

I suggest that you use `after_initialize` callback instead. Be careful though, since `after_initialize` will be called whenever the document is new or loaded from the db, that way you will have new guids every time you get the document, which is not what you want. So I suggest you do something like:

```
def set_guids 
  return unless theguid.nil?
  .....
end
```

As another solution, if you don't want to change the after_create callback above, you can do something like:

```
def theguid
  super || set_guids
end
```

That should let you go also.

Comment: doh! thanks! any recommedations where a guy who's relatively new to rails can go to learn the nuances of callbacks, which ones to use when, etc.?

Comment: Please read the new update to understand the impact of both solutions.